# uncaught type error on window.addEventListener pop-up window

Tags: javascript, events, dom, popup, typeerror

I'm getting a type error undefined in Chrome but not safari when I trigger a popup window.

When the window open, these event listeners are triggered:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    window.opener.postMessage('ready','https://oaklanding.myshopify.com');
    console.log("READY")
})
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    storeInfo = event.data
    console.log("storeInfo: ", storeInfo)
    var url = event.data.url
    console.log("event.data.url: ", url)
    if (url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url.substring(url.indexOf('?')));
        globalVariant = urlParams.get('variant')
        console.log(globalVariant)
        getInfo(storeInfo, parseInt(globalVariant))
    } else {
        getInfo(storeInfo, -1)
    }
    updateAccount()
}, false)
```

which results in the following errors in console:
[image: Image of console errors]

I have tried wrapping these event listeners in a function and calling that function on `DOMContentLoaded` but that doesn't work.

The data, such as `event.data.url` is eventually found however when I attempt to type information into a form it gives me another uncaught type error:

[image: uncaught type error on form fill]

It seems the events are triggered before the DOM is loaded...
I don't know why this only happens on Chrome but works perfectly in Safari and Chrome incognito?

Comment: The error is self descriptive...`event.data.url` is undefined, there is no `indexOf()` in `undefined`.....

Comment: Until you define `event.data.url` you cannot use `indexOf()`. Your console log clearly shows `event.data.url` is undefined so I would suggest you fix that before trying to do anything else.